# Choosing Primary key for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, primary-key, data-modeling

A bit of context: I am trying to build an inventory to list my AWS resources in various accounts and I am planning to use DynamoDB to store the data. These will be the columns for my table: ResourceARN, ResourceName, ResourceType, StandardTag, IsDeleted, LastUpdateTime and ResourceCreationDate ( this field is available only for a few resource types like Ec2).

Question: I want to query my DDB table using account ID, resource type and tag name. I am stumped on choosing the primary key for the table. Since primary key should be unique and has to have 1:many relationship. Hence, I cannot use a combination of resourceType and account Id.  Nor can I use resourceArn as my primary key since it is 1:1 relationship. Also, using the resourceARN as the sort key does not make sense to me. I understand that I can use a simple scan operation, but that is very costly and will take time if I add more data in my DDB.

I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance over the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

- Partition key: Account ID
- Sort key: `<resource type>/<resource ID>`

## Rationale

It's a common pattern for a sort key to be a string concatenating multiple attributes. Since sort keys [can be queried by prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions), you can leverage this in your queries:

- Get all account resources: query all sort keys on the Account ID partition key
- Get all EC2 instances of an account: query with `partition key = <your account ID>` and `sort key begins_with('ec2-instance')`.

You may notice that ARNs follow such a [hierarchy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) as well (what's probably not a coincidence). This would be effectively using a subset of the ARN as the sort key.

Some notes:

- DynamoDB is about *attributes* as much as about *columns*. You don't need to include `ResourceCreationDate` in the records which don't have it, and doing so will save you space (see next point).
- Attribute names count as storage *for every record*, which impacts cost and also throughput. It's common to use shorthand for names for this reason (`rct` instead of `ResourceCreationTime` for example).
- You can use LSIs (Local Secondary Indexes) to order by creation and update times if you need this.